# Loading Data into Mysql database

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-server

I have a text file which i would want to load into mysql database on Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS. I have entered the data into the file trey.txt and i moved the file to /tmp directory. When i move to the db, and enter the command

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE '/tmp/trey.txt'
into table arp_table
columns terminated by '|';
the output is

 ERROR 13(HY000):Can't get stat of '/tmp/trey.txt'(Errcode: 2)
```

How should i modify to enter these details. And can i run this from command line as a cron job.

Comment: This is usually a permissions problem.  MySQL cannot see the file.

Comment: So how do i modify the permissions

Comment: Use chmod 777 on the directory and file on linux

Comment: Also try it like this: LOAD DATA LOCAL
INFILE

Answer (score 0):

Put your data file in root folder after that run the command

```
$ sudo mysql -u root -p <database name>

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/trey.txt' INTO TABLE pet;
```